# bxslider doesn´t show correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a bxslider component with a  that loads pictures. If the slider has no images, it shows a default image, but if you have one image, it is shown twice.

How can I remedy it?

Comment: This sounds familiar, and if I'm right the solution is to edit the source of bxslider to prevent this behaviour (i.e. not loop/cycle on an array with a single element) - there is no option to turn it off.